# ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE doesn't work when there's an UPDATE trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers, lastinsertid

I have an `INSERT` statement that looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO officer (officer_number,
                     name,
                     bank_id)    
VALUES ('',
        '',
        8)

ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE officer_number = '',
                        name = '',
                        bank_id = 8,
                        id = LAST_INSERT_ID(id)
```

This way of doing it has been working just fine. It stopped working when I added the following trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER officer_update BEFORE UPDATE ON `officer`
FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.updated_at = NOW(), NEW.created_at = OLD.created_at
```

It's not that the `officer` record isn't getting inserted. It just seems that the trigger is hijacking `LAST_INSERT_ID()` or something. I say this because the next query that's executed is this:

```
INSERT INTO account (import_id,
                     branch_id,
                     account_number,
                     officer_id,
                     customer_id,
                     open_date,
                     maturity_date,
                     interest_rate,
                     balance,
                     opening_balance)
VALUES ('123',
        '4567',
        '789',
        '0', # This is the officer id which is of course invalid
        '321',
        '1992-04-22',
        '2012-05-22',
        '0.0123',
        '0',
        '10000')
```

Since I've run dozens of successful imports with the same exact file, I haven't changed my code, and now my imports aren't working after I added this trigger, I must deduce that the trigger is the culprit. I had a similar situation with another table and removing the trigger fix the problem.

So my questions are:

1. **Can someone explain what,
   specifically, is causing my officer
   id to get set to 0?**
2. **What's a good
   solution to this problem?**

I have another trigger on `officer.created_at` (and a lot of other tables' `created_at`s) and I would prefer to avoid some sort of awkward solution where I have a trigger on `created_at` but a `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` on `updated_at`. For some reason, MySQL only allows one auto-timestamp per table, so I can't do `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` for both `created_at` and `updated_at`.

Here is the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for `officer`:

```
CREATE TABLE `officer` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `officer_number` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `bank_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `officer_number` (`officer_number`,`name`),
  UNIQUE KEY `officer_number_2` (`officer_number`,`bank_id`),
  KEY `bank_id` (`bank_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `officer_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`bank_id`) REFERENCES `bank` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=102735 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: Could you please post the results of `SHOW CREATE TABLE officer` and the query which works incorrectly? Your title says `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` but there is no such query in the post.

Comment: Woops. Good catch. I've updated the question.

Comment: Can you please paste your code that you use to *retireve* the value of `LAST_INSERT_ID()`? seems to be working fine on my machine MySql 5.1.53

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` appears to be a way of preventing an error if `officer_number` already exists.  Do you need the update to happen (to fire the TRIGGER), or could you instead use `INSERT IGNORE`?:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO officer (officer_number,
                     name,
                     bank_id)    
VALUES ('',
        '',
        8);
```

That would simply do nothing if `officer_id` already exists, thus removing the need for the update (and therefore `LAST_INSERT_ID()`) altogether.

If that is not possible, then perhaps your `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` could be tweaked.  I'm not clear on the purpose of:

```
id = LAST_INSERT_ID(id)
```

`LAST_INSERT_ID()` (without any arguments), returns the first automatically generated value that was set for an AUTO_INCREMENT column by the most recently executed INSERT statement to affect such a column.

However, if you supply an argument, it returns the value of that argument, and the next call to `LAST_INSERT_ID()` (without any arguments), returns the same value.  For example:

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID(100);
+---------------------+
| LAST_INSERT_ID(100) |
+---------------------+
|                 100 |
+---------------------+

SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
+------------------+
| LAST_INSERT_ID() |
+------------------+
|              100 |
+------------------+
```

So, if we assume that `id == 100`, then this should be true:

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID(id);
+--------------------+
| LAST_INSERT_ID(id) |
+--------------------+
|                100 |
+--------------------+

SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
+------------------+
| LAST_INSERT_ID() |
+------------------+
|              100 |
+------------------+
```

Following on from that:

```
id = LAST_INSERT_ID(id)
```

Should be the same as:

```
id = id
```

Or, as suggested by Josh Davis, it shouldn't be necessary at all.  Have you tried simply `id = id`?  What exactly happens when you exclude it?

The [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) states that:

> However, if you mix references to
>   LAST_INSERT_ID() and
>   LAST_INSERT_ID(expr), the effect is
>   undefined

and:

> The ID that was generated is
>   maintained in the server on a
>   *per-connection* basis. This means that
>   the value returned by the function to
>   a given client is the first
>   AUTO_INCREMENT value generated for
>   most recent statement affecting an
>   AUTO_INCREMENT column *by that client*.
>   This value cannot be affected by other
>   clients, even if they generate
>   AUTO_INCREMENT values of their own.

As you are using both `LAST_INSERT_ID()` and `LAST_INSERT_ID(expr)`, the behaviour is undefined.  Furthermore, the TRIGGER may be regarded as being one connection (it's run directly on the server), whereas the INSERT and CREATE statements are possibly called from a different connection.  Given this, and the various changes and bugs that have been reported associated with LAST_INSERT_ID between versions, it's likely that there *will* be problems with your approach.

Going back to what Josh Davis said, I'd be inclined to resolve the use of `id = LAST_INSERT_ID(id)` in your INSERT statement.  It would also be helpful to know how you derive the `officer_id` in your `INSERT INTO account` statement - the one which is receiving a zero value.

Comment: Here's what I ended up doing: I used `INSERT IGNORE` but if I left it at that, the `LAST_INSERT_ID()` wouldn't come up right. After my `INSERT`, I just selected whatever record matched whatever I just inserted. It may not be the most succinct solution in the world but it works and I'm tired of messing around with it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you try to update the `id`. Can't you just remove the call to `LAST_INSERT_ID()`?

```
INSERT INTO officer (officer_number,
                     name,
                     bank_id)
VALUES ('',
        '',
        8)

ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE officer_number = '',
                        name = '',
                        bank_id = 8
```

Also, you should post your MySQL version (as well as the engine used), as there's been some changes to `LAST_INSERT_ID()` behaviour in the past.

Comment: It doesn't work without the `LAST_INSERT_ID()`. I'm using MySQL 5.1.49 and InnoDB.